# How do you separate 'and so' from the main part of a sentence?

Tags: commas

He has no control over what happens there, and disappointingly so. (in the sense that **had he had some control, it would be a lot better**)

Is the usage of 'and XXXXX so' right? Does it need a comma before 'and'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the usage is correct. The phrase is parenthetical, so it should be enclosed in commas, dashes, or parentheses.